# how can i filter my services list if i uncheck one of the checkbox from top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i am working on a small project and i am new with javascript and json. Can anybody help me to sort out the final step. i am very near to complete it, but i am facing some issue in it. i want to filter the results for example when i check Petromin, Showroom Sales and Service Center they will show their results and when i uncheck ( for example petromin ) it removes his value from those service list where his services available but if any other checkbox is still checked and its value also inside those list where pertromin value is already there then it should not remove.

here is my html code

```
<div id="checkbox_div">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Petromin">Petromin</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Used Cars">Used Cars</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Showroom Sales">Showroom Sales</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Service Center">Service Center</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Quick Service">Quick Service</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Spare Parts">Spare Parts</label>
</div>
<ol class="container"></ol>
```

and here is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data;
$('#checkbox_div input').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var serv_val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $.getJSON( "petromin-en.json", function(jdata) { 
            data = Object.entries(jdata);
            const filteredValues = data.filter(el => {
                return el[1].services_list.map(elem => elem.toLowerCase()).indexOf(serv_val) !== -1;
            });
            //console.log(data);
            filteredValues.forEach(function(obj) {
                var showroom_val = obj[1].name;
                var text_same = showroom_val;
                $('.showroom_name').filter(function () {
                    return $(this).text() === text_same;
                }).parent().remove();
                $('ol.container').append(
                    "<div class='inner'><h3 class='showroom_name'>"
                         + showroom_val +  
                    "</h3><li class='serv_list'>" 
                        + obj[1].services_list.join(', ') +
                    "</li></div>"
                );
            });
        });
    }    
    else if ($(this).not(":checked")){
        var uncheck_val = $(this).val();
        //
    }
});

</script>
```

and here is my json code

```
`{    "PETR734": {
    "dealerId": "PETR734",
    "name": "Riyadh Exit -14",
    "latitude": "24.698386",
    "longitude": "46.773247",
    "state": "Central",
    "city": "RIYADH",
    "language": "en",
    "phoneidentifiers": "frontdesk",
    "phones": "920023345",
    "email": "info@petromin.com",
    "contactWebsite": "https://www.nissan-petromin.com/",
    "services": "PA;SRVC;QS;PRTS",
    "dealerType": "AC",
    "canAcceptLeads": "y",
    "spokenLanguages": "ar;en",
    "dealerDescription": "Service Center",
    "services_list": [
        "Petromin",
        "Service Center",
        "Quick Service",
        "Spare Parts"
    ]
},
"PETR759": {
    "dealerId": "PETR759",
    "name": "Riyadh Exit 13",
    "latitude": "24.700901",
    "longitude": "46.770143",
    "state": "Central",
    "city": "RIYADH",
    "language": "en",
    "phoneidentifiers": "frontdesk",
    "phones": "920023345",
    "email": "info@petromin.com",
    "contactWebsite": "https://www.nissan-petromin.com/",
    "services": "PA;SRVC;QS;PRTS",
    "dealerType": "AC",
    "canAcceptLeads": "y",
    "spokenLanguages": "ar;en",
    "dealerDescription": "Service Center",
    "services_list": [
        "Petromin",
        "Service Center",
        "Quick Service",
        "Spare Parts"
    ]
},
"PETR764": {
    "dealerId": "PETR764",
    "name": "Hofouf (TS)",
    "latitude": "25.406250",
    "longitude": "49.465344",
    "state": "Eastern",
    "city": "Hofuf",
    "language": "en",
    "phoneidentifiers": "frontdesk",
    "phones": "920023345",
    "email": "info@petromin.com",
    "contactWebsite": "https://www.nissan-petromin.com/",
    "services": "PA;SRVC;QS;PRTS",
    "dealerType": "AC",
    "canAcceptLeads": "y",
    "services_list": [
        "Petromin",
        "Service Center",
        "Quick Service",
        "Spare Parts"
    ]
},
"PETR763": {
    "dealerId": "PETR763",
    "name": "Khobar (TS)",
    "latitude": "26.256590",
    "longitude": "50.201419",
    "state": "Eastern",
    "city": "KHOBAR",
    "language": "en",
    "phoneidentifiers": "frontdesk",
    "phones": "920023345",
    "email": "info@petromin.com",
    "contactWebsite": "https://www.nissan-petromin.com/",
    "services": "PA;SRVC;QS;PRTS",
    "dealerType": "AC",
    "canAcceptLeads": "y",
    "spokenLanguages": "ar;en",
    "dealerDescription": "Service Center",
    "services_list": [
        "Petromin",
        "Service Center",
        "Quick Service",
        "Spare Parts"
    ]
},
"PETR765": {
    "dealerId": "PETR765",
    "name": "Qassim (TS)",
    "latitude": "26.294617",
    "longitude": "43.991607",
    "state": "Central",
    "city": "Qassim",
    "language": "en",
    "phoneidentifiers": "frontdesk",
    "phones": "920023345",
    "email": "info@petromin.com",
    "contactWebsite": "https://www.nissan-petromin.com/",
    "services": "PA;SRVC;QS;PRTS",
    "dealerType": "AC",
    "canAcceptLeads": "y",
    "services_list": [
        "Petromin",
        "Service Center",
        "Quick Service",
        "Spare Parts"
    ]
},
"PETR753": {
    "dealerId": "PETR753",
    "name": "Khobar Rashid Mall",
    "latitude": "26.299159",
    "longitude": "50.181901",
    "state": "Eastern",
    "city": "KHOBAR",
    "language": "en",
    "phoneidentifiers": "frontdesk",
    "phones": "920023345",
    "email": "info@petromin.com",
    "contactWebsite": "https://www.nissan-petromin.com/",
    "services": "PA;SRVC;QS;PRTS",
    "dealerType": "AC",
    "canAcceptLeads": "y",
    "spokenLanguages": "ar;en",
    "dealerDescription": "Service Center",
    "services_list": [
        "Petromin",
        "Service Center",
        "Quick Service",
        "Spare Parts"
    ]
},
"PETR752": {
    "dealerId": "PETR752",
    "name": "Dammam Rayan",
    "latitude": "26.411388",
    "longitude": "50.092705",
    "state": "Eastern",
    "city": "DAMMAM",
    "language": "en",
    "phoneidentifiers": "frontdesk",
    "phones": "920023345",
    "email": "info@petromin.com",
    "contactWebsite": "https://www.nissan-petromin.com/",
    "services": "PA;SRVC;QS;PRTS",
    "dealerType": "AC",
    "canAcceptLeads": "y",
    "spokenLanguages": "ar;en",
    "dealerDescription": "Service Center",
    "services_list": [
        "Petromin",
        "Service Center",
        "Quick Service",
        "Spare Parts"
    ]
},
"PETR762": {
    "dealerId": "PETR762",
    "name": "Dammam (TS)",
    "latitude": "26.441723",
    "longitude": "50.048123",
    "state": "Eastern",
    "city": "DAMMAM",
    "language": "en",
    "phoneidentifiers": "frontdesk",
    "phones": "920023345",
    "email": "info@petromin.com",
    "contactWebsite": "https://www.nissan-petromin.com/",
    "services": "PA;SRVC;QS;PRTS",
    "dealerType": "AC",
    "canAcceptLeads": "y",
    "services_list": [
        "Petromin",
        "Service Center",
        "Quick Service",
        "Spare Parts"
    ]
},
"PETR767": {
    "dealerId": "PETR767",
    "name": "Tabuk (TS)",
    "latitude": "28.438009",
    "longitude": "36.466928",
    "state": "Western",
    "city": "Tabuk",
    "language": "en",
    "phoneidentifiers": "frontdesk",
    "phones": "920023345",
    "email": "info@petromin.com",
    "contactWebsite": "https://www.nissan-petromin.com/",
    "services": "PA;SRVC;QS;PRTS",
    "dealerType": "AC",
    "canAcceptLeads": "y",
    "services_list": [
        "Petromin",
        "Service Center",
        "Quick Service",
        "Spare Parts"
    ]
},
"PETR758": {
    "dealerId": "PETR758",
    "name": "Riyadh Thumama",
    "latitude": "28.830702",
    "longitude": "46.730938",
    "state": "Central",
    "city": "RIYADH",
    "language": "en",
    "phoneidentifiers": "frontdesk",
    "phones": "920023345",
    "email": "info@petromin.com",
    "contactWebsite": "https://www.nissan-petromin.com/",
    "services": "PA;SRVC;QS;PRTS",
    "dealerType": "AC",
    "canAcceptLeads": "y",
    "spokenLanguages": "ar;en",
    "dealerDescription": "Service Center",
    "services_list": [
        "Petromin",
        "Service Center",
        "Quick Service",
        "Spare Parts"
    ]
}}`
```

Comment: Basically, you need to evaluate all of the checkboxes every time any of them are clicked. I'll put up an example in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayData(filteredData){
    // wipe out the current dataset (to replace it with the new one). If filteredData.length === 0, then this will just clear the results.

    $('ol.container').html('');

    // put the newly found data into the container
    filteredData.forEach(location => {
        $('ol.container').append(
            `<div class='inner'>
                <h3 class='showroom_name'>${location.name}</h3>
                <li class='serv_list'>${location.services_list.join(', ')}</li>
            </div>`
        )
    })

}
function processData(){
    // get all checked checkboxes
    const checked = $('#checkbox_div input:checked');

    // iterate only the checked checkboxes
    checked.forEach(checkbox => {
        const currentService = checkbox.val().toLowerCase();
        const filteredData = jsondata.filter(location => location.services_list.includes(currentService));
        displayData(filteredData);
    })
}
$(function(){
    $('#checkbox_div input').click(function () {
        // All checkboxes do the same thing assuming that the data source is already available.
        // If not, then fetch the data first. This assumes that we have data in a global named jsondata.
        processData()
    });

})
```

I made some assumptions about your data here for naming purposes. This code is not tested, but I think that it conveys the idea.

Comment: actually first part of script is working fine...its filtering fine and giving it desire result.

Comment: and i don't know to filter values on uncheck

Comment: The way it is now, you can't unless you add some kind of "marker class" to the filtered data initially. Then, you could try to $(el).remove() those elements if checked === false.